# SharedPreferences with custom addition

Tags: android, shared

I was browsing through the net about `SharedPreferences` and I came across something that I've never seen in a SharedPreferences statement.

I wonder if anyone could explain to me what this means:

```
Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();
if(editText1CheckBox.isChecked){
     editor.putBoolean("STRING_NAME"+(a+100)+(b+100), false);
}else {
     editor.putBoolean("STRING_NAME"+(a+100)+(b+100), true);
}
```

Just to add on.

He also wrote

```
if(ClickData.ledOnOffControl[row][col]==OFF){
                    editor.putBoolean("ledData"+(row+100)+(col+100),false);
                }
                else{ 
                    editor.putBoolean("ledData"+(row+100)+(col+100),true);
                }
```

So I would appreciate if anyone could explain to mean what does the (a+100) and (b+100) means? What if it was a different variable/number? What does it mean?

Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion this is just a key for the boolean value.a & b would be integers already initialised.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

As I've guessed `a` and `b` are probably rows and columns based on your new code.

Since every checkbox needs to save it's own state he had to use unique strings and distinct them somehow. He chose to distinct them with row and column of the checkbox.

---

It seems that here the code had many check boxes and was saving the states of them.

E.g.

> STRING_NAME**101****101** = true (checkbox is checked)
>
> STRING_NAME**101****102** = false (checkbox is un-checked)

The `a+100` and `b+100` probably just refer to different checkboxes. Its a part of the unique preference name that's all.

Perhaps there were `a` rows and `b` columns. And each cell was a checkbox. So the developer decided (for some reason) to start the row and column indexes 100+. And looped through them saving the checkbox state.

Comment: So does that mean, if it was a SurfaceView and it has this for example (row+100)+(col+100). For every click on the SurfaceView(eg: LED ON), it will be saved in a SharedPreference?

Comment: @misleading93 what it means is that for every object that you want to save in the preferences you need a unique string to represent it.

Comment: The one line that I added was about a SurfaceView that when onClick on the LED, it will turn on the LED.

Comment: @misleading93 this does not turn on the led. It only saves the state. Also you are starting to fade away from your original question :)

Comment: What I meant was. The line that I added was meant for a SurfaceView with the LED. As per the IF statement, it has an array attached to the IF statement with [row][col]. So when it states (row+100)+(col+100). I still did not get what it meant.

Comment: @misleading93 It's referring to leds that are on a *table*. row and col are variables that are used to refer to specific led (*table cell*). He may as well written `+row+""+col` that would just start at 00 and go up to as many led rows and cols there are.

Comment: Well. I gavae it a try but nothing changed though. It didn't send any signals in anyways. But I guess I gotta figure this out myself haha. Thank you

Comment: @misleading93 you asked to explain the code, it got explained :) I'm not sure what you expected.

Comment: Yeah. I know. I needed kind of more in depth / detailed explanation. Was trying to surf the net for this kind of statement but can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 0):

Each Statement is generating a `SharedPreferences` with one unique Key. In other words, if we have let's say 3 values for `a` and 2 values for `b`, there are 6 different keys and therefore there are 6 different `SharedPreferences` for saving data.

Here is an Example:

```
Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i ++)
{
   editor.putBoolean("myKey"+i, false);
}
```

In this example, I have 6 different keys: `"myKey0"`, `"myKey1"`, `"myKey2"`, etc.